# Base table or view not found Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, model

When doing demo laravel in this page : https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers#eloquent-model-for-the-nerds
I got this error : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.nerds' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `nerds`). 
I have created Model Nerd. Please help me with this error. Many thanks

Here is my image Error : 
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU9xA.png)

Comment: What is the name of your database?

Comment: My database name is : laravel4, my table name is nerds.

Comment: Laravel is searching for homestead database.can you show the database.php code ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are successfully ran the migration.

check your database for nerds table.

ELoquent model Nerd assumes that you have a table named nerds in your database. If you have a different name for the table, mention it inside the class as,

```
protected $table = 'table_name';
```

Edit:

i've gone through the demo tutorial. Its not beginner friendly. There isn't any information on dealing with migrations and database.

[Database](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database) 
[Migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations)

Comment: I ran the migration successfully, I had table nerds in my database. But I don't know why I can't use $nerds = Nerd::all() in my controller.

Comment: what is the laravel version?

Comment: I used laravel homestead version 4.2

Comment: check your database configuration on App/config/local/database.php

Comment: Here is my config file :   'mysql' => array(
   'driver'    => 'mysql',
   'host'      => 'localhost',
   'database'  => 'laravel4',
   'username'  => 'root',
   'password'  => '',
   'charset'   => 'utf8',
   'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
   'prefix'    => '',
  ),

Comment: nope. its connecting to database named homestead. what is you environment set to? do u have a .env file?

Comment: I don't know why my db name is homestead. I set up laravel homestead with vagrant and vitualhost. I don't know where is file .env?

Comment: do you have the database.php under local direcotory? App/config/local/database.php . if not create the local directory and copoy the database.php .

Comment: Yeah, I replace that file and I got this error : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Finally it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Migration File

```
Schema::table('table_name', function ($table)  {
    // ...
});
```

Change it to

```
Schema::create('table_name', function ($table)  {
    // ...
});
```

I hope it will work